# JSON displays on screen after admin login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, canvas-lms

We've just followed the [Canvas LMS Quick Start](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Quick-Start) and successfully started our Canvas LMS on Ubuntu LTS. After running the server, we browsed to home page, logged in for the first time, and accepted the terms of use, after which Canvas displays the following API response.

[image: After accepting terms of use, JSON displays.]

We're very new to Rails. What's going on here? The expected result instead of this is to see a graphic user interface for the Canvas LMS.

We have tried running:

```
psql canvas_development -c "select message from error_reports"
```

It returns `(0 rows)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open the root URL of http://localhost:3000/ to access the UI for Canvas.

If that doesn't work then it would be helpful to get a list of the network requests that are causing you to be redirected there.